# jQuery keypress apostrophe

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I make the apostrophe key event work? I tried to put a backslash in front of it, but it doesn't seem to work. Sorry, I know it's a super basic question...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="check"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which === 48) {
            zero = true;
            keyMsg = "0 = ";
            checkKey(zero);
        }
    });
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which === 44) {
            apss = true;
            keyMsg = "\' = ";
            checkKey(apss);
        }
    });
    function checkKey(key) {
        if (key === true) {
            $(".check").html(keyMsg + "true");
        }
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes i tested for all letters, lower case, upper case, numbers and various symbols. so far only apostrophe doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct key code for `'` is 39.

In Firefox, there is a keyborad shortcut that triggers "Quick Find within link-text only" when `'` is pressed, so you will have to use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent that.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gLxjnLd/)

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which === 48) {
        zero = true;
        keyMsg = "0 = ";
        checkKey(zero);
    }
});

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which === 39) {
        e.preventDefault();
        apss = true;
        keyMsg = "' = ";
        checkKey(apss);
    }
});

function checkKey(key) {
    if (key === true) {
        $(".check").html(keyMsg + "true");
    }
}
```